# Change text inside anchor tag on toggle?

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

[image]

So right now I'm toggling `ul.children` like this:

```
$('a.expand-cat-item').on('click', function() {
  $(this).closest('li.cat-item').find('ul.children').toggle('slow');
});
```

Now, I would also change the + sign into a - sign inside `a.expand-cat-item` (which will work as a toggle too).

How to accomplish that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use condition operator `? :` to make a text switch condition.

```
$('a.expand-cat-item').on('click', function() {
  $(this).closest('li.cat-item').find('ul.children').toggle('slow');
  $(this).text($(this).text() == "+" ? "-" : "+");
});
```

Comment: is text implicitly the content or does `text` need set somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('a.expand-cat-item').on('click', function() {
  $(this).closest('li.cat-item').find('ul.children').toggle('slow');
  if ($(this).text() == '+ '){
      $(this).text('- ');
  }
  else{
      $(this).text('+ ');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$('a.expand-cat-item').text("- ");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a.expand-cat-item').on('click', function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.closest('li.cat-item').find('ul.children').toggle('slow');
   var html = '+';
   if($this.html().indexOf('+') > -1){
       html = '-';
   }
   $this.html(html);
});
```